# Can a fruit fly move through a large bubble without popping it?

Tags: surface-tension, bubbles

Assume what logistics you need to in order for something like this to be possible.
Can a fruit fly move through a large bubble without popping it?

Comment: A bubble of what, Alex? If it's soap, from experience, I know ants won't cross soap until it's dry.

Comment: Yes soap, but if other kinds of bubbles are stronger I would be interested to learn about them.

Comment: @AcidJazz Couldn't agree more, your support and presence will be missed. Hope our paths cross in the world of physics some day. Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get through the wall of the bundle,  I think you can ignore surface tension, as the fly has to ""cut" through it.

The air pressure inside any spherical  bubble is higher than atmosphere pressure so I don't believe the fly will make it through.

From this post [Air Pressure inside Soap Bubbles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/127695/why-is-the-pressure-inside-a-soap-bubble-higher-than-outside), the higher air pressure will obviously escape to the atmosphere, and with soap bubbles, I can't see how that could not result in the wall of the bubble bursting at a very rapid rate.

It would probably give the light fruit flies a free ride, as the air escaped suddenly in the opposite direction to the direction the fly originally  was trying to move in.

With heavier material bubble walls, the bubble would still collapse around the fly, even if it did manage to cut its way through.

At higher altitudes, the "getting through the bubble"  problem for the fly increases,  as differential air pressure between the inside and out of the bubble increases, making the bubble more likely to collapse.

[image]

This is a fruit fly trap, made of bubbles, The flies are attracted by the bait and get stuck in the soap bubbles. Red wine is used as bait and some dish soap is added. A cover is put on top and the glass is shaken  to make the bubbles.

From personal experience,  animals with antennae, such as flies and ants,  will stay away from the walls of soap bubbles, as the soap overwhelms their sense of smell and taste.

Comment: What about a soap bubble attached to the surface of water sort of like a milk bubble on milk, I can put my finger in and out of those without them popping.

Comment: Total guess, on a liquid surface the bubble has more flexibility,  it can take more "abuse" without popping, unlike a bubble on a  solid surface, where the air pressure inside the bubble is too much for the walls of the bubble to cope with, result: (small) bang.

Answer (score 1):

I did not try it myself, but, according to www.chymist.com/soap%20bubbles%20part%202.pdf , "You can catch a bubble or put your finger, hand, or even an arm through a soap film without
breaking it by first spreading the soap solution over the skin surface. As long as a surface or your skin is wet, even with water, soap bubbles generally will not break when they contact that surface." Maybe the same is true for a fly.

Comment: Absolutely true, it happens every time I wash dishes by hand. Bubbles remain unpopped  as long as my hand stays wet.

Comment: @Acid Jazz: Thank you for the confirmation. However, why did not you write so in your answer? Just curious.

Comment: Well, it's your answer and your valid point, you thought of it and (and I did not), so imo,  it should remain attached to your answer by comments.

Comment: @Acid Jazz: No, what I meant asking the question, I was surprised that you did not write about your experience with "poking" bubbles with wet fingers in your answer before I wrote my answer. However, you have answered my question, saying "I did not thought of it").

Comment: Actually @Alex asked the question about poking bubbles, with wet fingers, not I. Anyway, the main thing is Alex got answers, but I bet there will be more questions from Alex tomorrow :)

Comment: @AcidJazz: well, he did not mention wet fingers:-)

Comment: @AcidJazz Haha what can I say, physics really brings out the curiosity in me!