# When surface tension acts parallel to the interface, then why is the pressure inside a spherical drop greater than the pressure outside it?

Tags: surface-tension

When I was watching a Youtube video explaining why pressure inside a drop is greater than the pressure of the air outside, surface tension was drawn as acting radially inwards from the spherical surface of the liquid drop. Hence, because there is both the force due to the air pressure acting over the surface area of the drop and the surface tension of the drop acting inwards, for the drop to be at equilibrium (i.e. not contracting or expanding), the pressure of the liquid in the drop has to be greater than the pressure of the air. I have taken a screenshot of the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Us7sk1OrcUc&t=225s (at 3:45) to show this. This explanation was very intuitive to me. However, the explanation uses the fact that surface tension acts perpendicular to the surface of the liquid (and hence the force due to surface tension is radially inwards), whereas my NCERT Textbook said that surface tension acts parallel to the interface. This is confusing me, and I can't understand which is true: does the surface tension act parallel to the surface (if so, why is pressure inside a liquid drop greater than the air pressure outside) or does the surface tension act perpendicular to the surface (if so, why does my textbook and so many other sources say that it acts parallel to the surface of the liquid)? Thanks.
[image: Please note that here F_S is the force due to surface tension]

Comment: The droplet's boundary is curved, so the resultant of the tangential forces points inward. You should look into the derivation of the Young-Laplace equation or the Gibbs-Thomson equation.

Comment: See, for instance, this [pedagogical paper](https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1119/1.2117127).

Comment: Did you have a look at this? - [Why is the pressure inside a soap bubble higher than outside?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/127709/238167); I think that diagram must make it obvious.